# I don't know why my method won't work (if statements)

Tags: java

This program classifies quadrilaterals. I'm not sure why my  method just won't work, the coordinates I used were (08,4),nd (5,5). All my other methods work so I don't think its because of my formula.

Comment: You can add items in if statement  without putting in proper brackets.

Comment: `if((ab + bc) == (cd + da) || (bc + cd) == (da + ab)){}`

Comment: You haven't explained why `isKite()` doesn't work. What's the error?

Comment: It just won't output that it's a kite, even though I calculated it myself and determined that it matches my formula and method. (coordinates: (0,0),(7,1),(8,4), and (5,5))

Comment: thank you! @Smit the brackets were the issue

Comment: Ok i will add that as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if((ab + bc) == (cd + da) || (bc + cd) == (da + ab)){}`

If you dont put brackets the compiler will look at the precedence of the element.

Comment: precedence was correct. formula wasn't. it's not a kite.

Answer (score 0):

if((ab == bc && cd == da) || (bc == cd && da == ab))

in your case any rectangle is kite  ( 1 + 2 == 1 + 2)

Comment: and any parallelogram :))

Comment: would rhombus be the same as yours too then?

Comment: because it is a kite. like square is also rhombus, kite, rectangle and parallelogram